# Using json with listview in Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a dummy listview that I have setup in my app that uses the following code:

```
public class Roster extends Activity {
      private ListView mainListView ;
      private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_roster);

         // ListView resource. 
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.rosterListView );

        // List of names.
        String[] players = new String[] { "Dude1", "Guy2"};  
        ArrayList<String> playerlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        playerlist.addAll( Arrays.asList(players) );

        //ArrayAdapter using the list.
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rosterrow, playerlist);

        // Add more Players, If you passed a String[] instead of a List<String> 
        // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items. 
        // Otherwise an exception will occur.
        listAdapter.add( "Person8" );


        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );      
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

      }
```

which gives me a listview of three players. 
I now want to use the json object to populate the list instead of using a string. How can I populate the list using my json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the value of Json by key and put it in to string array.

```
JsonObject myjsondata = new JsonObject(jsondata.toString());

String[] players = new String[] {myjsondata.getString("key") , myjsondata.getString("key1")};
```